# Переполнение типа double при вычислении математических функций

Tags: c++, double

Помогите разобраться. У меня есть код, в котором я подключаю проверку на переполнение типа double с помощью функции `_finite()` относительно математических операций, а не через присваивание переменных. В консоли для z выводит ошибку OVERFLOW error. Возможно ли в этом случае обойтись без обработки исключений? Компилятор - C++Builder 6. Буду очень благодарен.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    double x = 10E200;
    double y = 10E400;
    double z = pow(x, 2);
    if(_finite(x) != 0)
    {
        cout << "This is finite number: " << x << endl;
    }
    else cout << "This is infinity: " << x << endl;
    if(_finite(y) != 0)
    {
        cout << "This is finite number: " << y << endl;
    }
    else cout << "This is infinity: " << y << endl;
    if(_finite(z) != 0)
    {
        cout << "This is finite number: " << z << endl;
    }
    else cout << "This is infinity: " << z << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Update: Это моя вина, многие не поняли, чего я хотел, поэтому добавлю второй пример. Через `pow()` или `x * x` выводит ошибку о переполнении. Как мне корректно проверить условие, чтобы не выводило ошибку?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    double x;
    char str[] = "Введите число, которое мы будем возводить в степень: ";
    CharToOem(str,str);
    cout << str;
    cin >> x;
    int check = 0; // флаг переполнения
    do
    {
        if(_finite(pow(x, 2)) != 0)
        {
            x = pow(x, 2);
            cout << x << endl;
        }
        else check = 1;
    }
    while(check == 0);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: используй какую-либо подходящую тебе библиотеку bignum

Comment: @Cirran, только выводит не `OVERFLOW error` (по крайней мере у меня), а Ваше сообщение

    This is infinity: inf

А чего вы ожидали, если 1,7×10+308 это максимальное число для типа double?

Comment: Я использую gcc, так что помочь видимо не смогу.

Comment: @avp ну у каждого свои недостатки. Когда нибудь это (использование gcc) Вам зачтётся.

Comment: @Cirran, я думаю такое поведение pow (вывод сообщения) в C++Builder должно как-то управляться. Надо либо поискать в документации, либо более конкретно сформулировать вопрос. 

**Вопрос именно о сообщении, выводимом pow.**

Comment: @Cirran величина Вашей жертвы вызывает недоумение. gdb явно лучше отладчика от Borland. И намного лучше.

Comment: @Cirran, что значит "программа крашится. Как обработать?". 

Какой у Вас компилятор и ОС?

Я добавил в Вашу программу умножение x на x

    double z = pow(x, 2);
    
    printf ("z = x * x = %lf\n",
     z = x * x);

и запустил (это \*eshell\* в Emacs Windows 7 32 bit). Вот результат

    c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ g++ flt.c 
    c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
    z = x * x = 1.#INF00
    This is finite number: 1e+201
    This is infinity: inf
    This is infinity: inf
    c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ echo $?
    0
    c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $

  
IMHO ничто не упало.

Comment: Может быть, функция pow не умеет работать с такими большими числами? Попробуйте умножение вместо pow.

Comment: @VladD Прототип стандартный - `double pow(double x, double y)`. Просто размерность `pow()` такая же, как у `double` - `1.7 * 10E308`. Мне не нужно получить большое число при возведении в степень, надо, чтобы не выводило ошибку при переполнении. Обновил пример кода выше.

Comment: @Cirran: Хм. А что говорит официальная документация об этой функции? Может быть, это документированное поведение при переполнении?

Comment: @VladD: Функция `_matherr` может обрабатывать ошибки при вычислении мат. функций. Только в том то и дело, что я не знаю, как ловить исключения с помощью `_try()\ _catch()\ _throw()`.

Comment: @Cirran: ну, работает как-то не так функция pow? Ну так и в официальную документацию именно по ней надо смотреть, а не пытаться угадать. Вы уверены, что она бросает исключение, или это догадка?

Comment: @VladD: Правильно она работает. Смотрел по встроенному хелпу в C++Builder 6. Просто она не может вернуть значение, больше размерности типа `double`, вот и выводит в консоли ошибку: `pow: OVERFLOW error`.

Comment: @Cirran: а можно добавить в вопрос копипаст этого хелпа? Если там сказано, что при переполнении выводится такая ошибка, то так тому и быть. Если сказано, что это можно обойти, значит, можно. Если нет, то нет. PS: а при умножении тоже такая ошибка?

Comment: Резюме дискуссии: C++Builder -- фтопку. Другие продукты фирмы Borland -- туда же. Нарушения стандартов можно простить Майкрософту -- он большой и толстый, а борзую мелочь пузатую -- давить.

Comment: @alexlz: в последнее время MS, кстати, очень сильно следит за соответствием стандарту. Они не очень быстры в поддержке новых фич, но отношение типа "наш компилятор тока для виндов, стандарты идут лесом" давно уже не наблюдается.

Comment: @avp, @VladD, @alexlz: Всем большое спасибо за помощь, тему можно закрывать. На Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 оба примера скомпилировались успешно. Думал, ошибка в моем коде, а не от особенностей разных сред разработки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Через pow() или x * x выводит ошибку о переполнении. Как мне корректно проверить условие, чтобы не выводило ошибку?

Если я ничего не путаю: `( a * e ^ x ) * ( b * e ^ y ) = c * e ^ ( x + y + z )`, где `z` - экспонента получаемая при перемножении `a` на `b`, а `c` - остаточная мантисса от этой операции.

Т.е. чтобы определить, будет ли переполнение, можно просто умножить целочисленную экспоненту на `n` (показатель степени - второй параметр функции `pow`) и проверить, выходит ли это значение за пределы используемого диапазона ( для `double` - это [`1024`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Число_двойной_точности)).

Если не выходит, нужно выделить **остаточную** экспоненту от квадрата мантиссы, добавить к ней вычисленное ранее произведение и проверить на выход за границы снова. Вобщем - достаточно муторно, но не смертельно.

Чтобы выделить остаточную экспоненту, нужно выполнить целочисленное умножение `64-битных` мантисс. Предварительно, нужно маской удалить из них экспоненту (те самые `11 бит`) и привести [обратным кодом](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обратный_код) в натуральный диапазон. После умножения - обнулить старший бит, и посчитать число правых сдвигов результата до того момента, пока эти `11 бит` не обнулятся.

Число этих сдвигов и дают остаточную экспоненту.

p.s.: экспоненты - тоже знаковые, это следует учитывать при их сложении, вернее - при проверке на выход за пределы границ диапазона (для этого, надо перевести `11-битную` экспоненту в `short`, заполняя оставшиеся `5 старших бит` значением старшего бита этой экспоненты).

Comment: @mega: Да, я хотел решить именно так, как Вы описали - проверить на переполнение, не вызывая при этом самого переполнения. :) Правда, у меня было так: `(a * e^x) * (b * e^y) = a * b * e^(x + y)`. Если `x + y > 308`, завершить цикл. Но Ваше решение более правильное, так как умножение a * b тоже в результате дает некоторый прирост экспоненты.

Comment: Далее мне осталось разобраться, как разложить вещественное число на знак, экспоненту и мантиссу, если число представляется в виде: `sign * 2^exponent * mantissa`. Из статьи на Википедии ясно, что под `sign` выделяется 1 бит, под `exponent` 11 бит, под `mantissa` 52 бита. Только я не знаю, как число разделить на биты, и записать соответствующее значение, куда надо. Понимаю, что все это в двоичном виде, но не знаю как.

Comment: Кажется, нашел подходящую мат.функцию `frexp`, сейчас пример напишу.

Comment: Да, `frexp` уже все делает сама. Теперь результат `frexp` нужно возвести в квадрат и снова вызвать `frexp`. Это даст остаточную экспоненту:

 bool can_pow( double x, int n ){
   int y, z;
   c = frexp( x, &y );
   frexp( c*c, &z );
   return abs( y * n + z ) <= 308;
 }

Comment: Дано: `a*10^x = b*2^y`
Найти: `a - ?`

Comment: @mega: Ух, вы даже предусмотрели случай, когда число близко к бесконечности, но не равно ему, например, `1.6E+308`. Это идеальное математическое решение, а главное, кроссплатформенное!
Мое решение свелось к виду:

    double x, mantissa, y, n;
    int exponent;
    int check = 0; // флаг переполнения
    do
    {
     mantissa = frexp(x, &exponent);
        if(abs(exponent) < 308)
        {
            x = pow(x, n);
            cout << x << endl;
        }
        else check = 1;
    }
    while(check == 0);

Но ваше решение, конечно, гораздо лучше.

Comment: Только обращайте внимание на то, что `frexp` возвращает двоичные,а не десятичные значения: я `can_pow` уже не могу скорректировать, комментарий ушел в историю :) Последний `return` верный.

Comment: отличный ответ! +1